# Exception EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION playing audio in swift 2

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, ios9

I am trying to get audio to play, in swift 2, but I get an error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)
```

something changes from swift 1 to 2, so I put in the do catch phrase, but now it doesn't work
Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var PausePlay: UIButton!


-->  var ButtonAudioURl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Tutava", ofType: "aif")!)

var ButtonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    do {
        ButtonAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURl)
    } catch _ {
    }
}

@IBAction func PlayAudio(sender: AnyObject) {

    ButtonAudioPlayer.play()

}
}
```

Who can help me? thx

Comment: Xcode is a development environment and not relevant to your question.  Show the stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: it happens where i declare var ButtonAudioURL

Comment: What if you initialize `ButtonAudioURL` inside `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: nothing changes, I get the same error

Comment: You can't as that variable declaration is not doing anything now.  It should be empty.  Remove the (pointless) initialization of `ButtonAudioPlayer` as well as that is already being initialized in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: but then comes the message: use if unresolved identifier 'ButtonAudioPlayer'?

Comment: I said move the initialization into `viewDidLoad`, not to remove the variable.

Comment: then the message: "variable 'ButtonAudioPlayer' was written to, but never read"

Comment: That's all what's in the console? `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` is tied with unwrapping optionals (and others, but ...). Anything like this _fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value_ in console? If so, than the problem is in `!` - `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Tutava", ofType: "aif")!` You sure it's included in the target? Put `print(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Tutava", ofType: "aif"))` in your `viewDidLoad` and send the console output when your view controller did appear.

Comment: And if you run your code in Xcode, where it stops? Which line?

Comment: You are right, the fatal error you guessed appears. So I putted the print(NSBundle...) line in ViewDidLoad and it return nil. Do you know the problem?

Answer (score 1):

So at last I found the problem. I had to check the boxes 'add to targets' when I import the audio file.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I tested the line 'var ButtonAudioURL ...' in playground, the same error, then i added the sound file to playground resources, then it worked.